# Inflating Custom Linear Layouts at runtime

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Following is my requirement:
1. I have a main linear layout defined.
2. I get an arraylist from an Api.

Now, I want to add custom Linear Layouts with 1 imageView and 1 textView and feed values to these from the API data.

The above linear layouts will be added in the main linear layout with vertical orientation.

Custom Linear Layout class:

```
public class LandingPageLinearLayout extends LinearLayout{

    private ImageView iv_outletInfo_Icon;
    private TextView tv_outletInfo;

    public LandingPageLinearLayout(Context context, String tv_value, int iv_drawable_id) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        /* View view =  LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.landing_page_ll_custom, null);*/

         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                inflater.inflate(R.layout.landing_page_ll_custom, this, true);


         iv_outletInfo_Icon = (ImageView) getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.imgview_outletInfoIcon);
         iv_outletInfo_Icon.setBackgroundResource(iv_drawable_id);

         tv_outletInfo = (TextView) getChildAt(1).findViewById(R.id.tv_outletInfo);
         tv_outletInfo.setText(tv_value);



        // this.addView(view);

    }

}
```

The xml layout of the Custom Linear Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.iwillcode.interfaces.LandingPageLinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="14dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgview_outletInfoIcon"
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_outletInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="3.5"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</com.iwillcode.interfaces.LandingPageLinearLayout>
```

The method called in the activity:

```
 private void generateTextViews(int n, LinearLayout mainLinearLayout){
        // Dynamic generation of TextViews as per requirement
        // n = size of arrayList

        final LandingPageLinearLayout[] myTextViews = new LandingPageLinearLayout[n];
         hashMap = new HashMap<String,String>();

         //RatingBar Linear Layout


        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            // create a new Custom Linear Layout

            hashMap = arraylist_outletInfo.get(i);

            String name = hashMap.get(Config.KEY_NAME);
            String value = hashMap.get("value"); 

            if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("rating")){
                ll_ratingLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 tv_rating.setText(hashMap.get("value"));
                 ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat(value));

            }

            final LandingPageLinearLayout rowCustomView = new LandingPageLinearLayout(context,value,R.drawable.outlet_icon);

            // Set text of rowTextView
           // rowTextView.setText("This is row #" + i+value);

            // Condition for alternate colors

            if(n%2==0){
                rowCustomView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
              }else{
                rowCustomView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f2f2f2"));
              }         

            // add the textview to the linearlayout
            mainLinearLayout.addView(rowCustomView);

            // save a reference to the textview for later
           // myTextViews[i] = rowTextView;
        }


    }
```

LogCat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.goldvip.crownit/com.goldvip.crownit.LandingPageActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.goldvip.interfaces.LandingPageLinearLayout
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2345)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5315)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:736)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.goldvip.interfaces.LandingPageLinearLayout
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:616)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
       at com.goldvip.interfaces.LandingPageLinearLayout.<init>(LandingPageLinearLayout.java:26)
       at com.goldvip.crownit.LandingPageActivity.generateTextViews(LandingPageActivity.java:1777)
       at com.goldvip.crownit.LandingPageActivity.onCreate(LandingPageActivity.java:269)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5315)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:736)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:531)
       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:495)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:580)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
       at com.goldvip.interfaces.LandingPageLinearLayout.<init>(LandingPageLinearLayout.java:26)
       at com.goldvip.crownit.LandingPageActivity.generateTextViews(LandingPageActivity.java:1777)
       at com.goldvip.crownit.LandingPageActivity.onCreate(LandingPageActivity.java:269)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5315)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:736)
```

The App crashes when the activity is loaded.

Comment: May I kindly ask, did my solution worked ? If yes, please accept my answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Logcat says:
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:  [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]

you forgot to implement one of super class constructor, namely:
    LinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)

It`s getting called, because you are using your view in an XML.
Make sure to implement this two constructor as well:

> LinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
>
> LinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to the declare your custom view in the layout you need, at least, the constructor that takes `Context` and `AttributeSet` as parameter

```
public LandingPageLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr);
```

And you should avoid to overload the View's constructor. There is the possibility to declare custom attributes for your custom layout.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will helps you.

Add new line in XML after xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

-New line :  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/YourMainPackageName"

-Clean and build project.

- You have to add this when you are using any library.